# open angular 5 application from a parent MVC application

Tags: angular, model-view-controller

I am developing an Angular 5 application that needs to be opened from a parent MVC.net application in the next tab. It is also required to pass a few sensitive data to the angular application.

we have tried passing the values using post method within a form as below

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "Home");
form.setAttribute("target", "view");
var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "message");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "val");
form.appendChild(hiddenField);
document.body.appendChild(form);     
window.open('http://localhost:4200/home', 'angularapp');
form.submit();
```

Is there a way/what is the best approach here, that the angular application can read the values passed from its parent application

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it through url's route/query parameters. Then, read them through urlparams/queryparams in the Angular application's router. Data can be removed after reading, from the url.

Parent Application:

```
window.open('http://localhost:4200/home/Bijith/25', 'angularapp'); OR
window.open('http://localhost:4200/home?name=Bijith,age=25', 'angularapp');
```

Angular child application:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   console.log(route.snapshot.paramMap); OR
   console.log(route.snapshot.queryParamMap);
}
```

Comment: Can't this be passed in the body instead of query string?

Comment: As per my knowledge it is not possible.